# Can ESXi read CPU temperatures (and report them to Observium)? (Poweredge 1950 Gen 3)

Tags: cpu, temperature, esxi

Currently running ESXi 5.5, Poweredge 1950 Gen 3 with dual Xeon E5410's at 2.33GHz. As far as I can tell, ESXi does not report CPU temperature anywhere. Here is the health page on ESXi vSphere:

[image: esxi health status]

So all it's showing is the thermal trip, which really doesn't help at all.

My end goal is to get [Observium](http://www.observium.org/) to monitor those temperatures, which works fine with other machines I have running. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Vmware are fools who have mostly dropped SNMP support in their products.

Seemingly without any regard for their customers either, because this is one of the most common questions we get "why does x graphing not work on VMware?"

Comment: Well, that's great. So it's not only the fact that they don't have SNMP support, but they don't even support temp readings in the first place? Also, Observium rocks, thanks for putting in the effort to making it what it is.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but I had luck with the IPMI integration with my HP server for ILO2.

Fill in the IPMI settings for your device (in Observium under properties) test it with `ipmitool -H xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -U USER -P PASSWORD -I lanplus chassis status`  and I got all chassis temperature, incl. cpu in Observium.